# Have you ever reflected Reflector?

Tags: .net, reflector

Lutz Roeder's Reflector, that is.

Its obfuscated.

[image]

I still don't understand this.  Can somebody please explain?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would have been kind of ironic if it weren't ;-)

Answer (score 10):

I'll accept Keith's answer, but he's 180 degrees off.  Its ironic that the tool used to peer at the source of assemblies is obfuscated.

Also, I'm suprised how serious some of you are.  Lighten up!  What are you, cobol programmers?

<-- (edit:  Maybe some of you are!)

Comment: I'm laughing so hard right now...

Answer (score 6):

I'm curious what product he uses to obfuscate Reflector. Or maybe it's his custom solution - he obviously knows tons about IL.

Answer (score 5):

Of course, I did. For example to find out that .NET Reflector is obfuscated with Dotfuscator.

[DotfuscatorAttribute in Reflector.exe (version 5.1.6.0) http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/7f6eda286f.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/7f6eda286f.png)

Comment: Interesting.  I wonder if this is RedGate's doing.  I mean, Dotfuscator.  I don't remember seeing this way back in the olden days when I first reflected reflector.

Comment: @Will: I just checked out Lutz Roeder's .NET Reflector 5.0.25.0 (still available from Softpedia) from the beginning for 2007, and it was already obfuscated with Dotfuscator.

It's especially interesting that RedGate's still using Dotfuscator for .NET Reflector, although they have their own .NET obfuscator {smartassembly} (http://www.smartassembly.com/).

Answer (score 4):

It's always been the case that its been obfuscated. It was one of the first things I tried with it years ago ;).

Answer (score 2):

What needs explaining, Reflector isn't open source, Lutz decided to obfuscate to protect his IP. Fair game.

Answer (score 1):

It may have been obfuscated by tools such as Xenocode or Dotfuscator. Or as someone said, Lutz may know a lot about IL.

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to reflect it according to the EULA (if any) ? I would guess not, and not surprised that you can't.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your answer right here: [Reflector sold to Red Gate](http://blog.lutzroeder.com/2008/08/future-of-net-reflector.html)

Comment: no, actually Reflector was obfuscated like that from the beginning. It has nothing to do with red gate.

Comment: Well, it might: Lutz Loeder might have thought since the beginning he would try to make some money off Reflector, and therefore kept the code secret.